# How to substitute a series of keys into a string being displayed using javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby, haml

I have a set of templates that contain key phrases denoted by %%key%% (could use different delimiters if these are a problem).  In the code presented, the names of the templates are shown in a selector, and when selected, their values are presently being moved into a textarea for display.  Before they are displayed, I wish to go through the template and replace each key with the value associated with that key.

I have tried using template.gsub 'key' 'value', template.gsub! 'key' 'value', and even template['key'] = 'value', to no avail.  To eliminate other problems, I have tried using simple values for the 'value' and then displaying the result in an alert.  If I don't try the replacement, the alert shows the template.  If I try any of these attempts, I don't get the alert to show, indicating some kind of javascript error, I suppose.  I can't figure out what the error is.

Here is a part of the application_helper.rb:

```rb
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def render_haml(haml, locals = {})
    Haml::Engine.new(haml.strip_heredoc, format: :html5).render(self, locals)
  end

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def create_template_selector
    get_templates()
    render_haml <<-HAML
    %select{{name: "msg", id: "template_selector"}}
      - @t_hash.each do |name,message|
        %option{ :value => message }= name
    HAML
  end

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def get_templates()
    templates = Template.all
    @t_hash = Hash.new
    templates.each do |t|
      @t_hash[t.name] = t.message
    end
  end
```

and this is the view partial _text.html.haml, where the selector is embedded and its selection is presented when changed:

```
    = form_for(@comment, remote: true, html: {id: "#{id_prefix}_new_comment"}) do |f|
      = hidden_field_tag "comment[commentable_id]", commentable.id, id: "#{id_prefix}_comment_commentable_id"
      = hidden_field_tag "comment[commentable_type]", class_name.classify, id: "#{id_prefix}_comment_commentable_type"
      %div
        %h3 Select a Template
        = create_template_selector
        %div
          = f.text_area :comment, id: "#{id_prefix}_comment_comment", name:"text_msg"
          .buttons
          = image_tag("loading.gif", size: :thumb, class: "spinner", style: "display: none;")
          = f.submit t(:add_note), id: "#{id_prefix}_comment_submit"
          #{t :or}
          = link_to(t(:cancel), '#', class: 'cancel')
```

```
    :javascript
      $(document).ready( function() {
      $('#template_selector').change(function() {
        var data= $('select').find('option:selected').val();
        //
        // Here is where I put alert(data) and it works
        // but,
        // var filled = data.gsub '%%first_name%%' 'Ralph'
        // followed by alert(filled), shows no alert panel and no error
        //
        $("##{id_prefix}_comment_comment").val(data);
        });
      }  );
```

```
 How can I create a set of fill_ins like:
```

```rb
     def fill_ins()
        @fillins = Hash.new
        @fillins['%%first_name%%'] = 'Ralph'
        @fillins['%%last_name%%'] = 'Jones'
     ...
     end
```

and create a function like:

```rb
     def fill_in(template)
        @fi = fill_ins()
        @fi.each do 'fkey, fval'
           template.gsub! fkey fval
        end
      end
```

and have it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `:javascript` block, you should be writing JavaScript, not Ruby.

`String#gsub` is a Ruby method.

[`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) is a JavaScript method.

```
var filled = data.replace(/%%first_name%%/g, 'Ralph');
```

EDIT: Forgot that `replace` with a string only replaces once. Use regular expression with global flag instead.

Also: to pass the data from Ruby to JavaScript, use this pattern in your template:

```
<script>
  const fillIns = <%= fill_ins.to_json %>;
</script>
```

Then you can either loop that array and run the `replace` method with each pair (not optimal) — or you can use a regular expression that picks up on the general pattern of the variable:

```
var filled = data.replace(/%%([^%]+)%%/g, (_, name) => fillIns[name]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was obvious after you explained it!  I tried that and it did the one time replacement.  How about how I would access the fill_ins() in javascript and then in javascript do the replacement?  Should I do a string tokenizer and look up each word in the fill_ins() hash somehow?